# Crontab runs script but then shuts down immediately

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts, cron

I have a larger rscript (320 lines of code) running on an Ubuntu 20.04. When I run it as Rscript in the console, it works fine. However, when I run it via a cronjob, it does run (I can observe this with htop), but then hangs immediately.

I also ran the same script on my Raspberry Pi and found the same problems. The script runs correctly, but the cronjob ends without anything happening. Where can my error be?

I have even tried starting my script with sh. But again I had the same problem.

```
52 14 * * 1-5 sh /home/ubuntu/R/projects/scripts/corona/shell.sh
22 15 * * 1-5 Rscript /home/ubuntu/R/projects/scripts/corona/push.R
```

Comment: Capture output to see if there is anything `... >> /path/to/logfile`.

Comment: How do I do that?

Comment: ... and errors as well... append `>> /path/to/logfile 2>&1` to the command(s) in your crontab (for some appropriate value of `/path/to/logfile` for example `/home/username/cron.log`)

Comment: Jobs run through `cron`, or `at`, or `batch`, aren't run in the same runtime environment that you have on your desktop. None of your `PATH` changes, or other environment  variable settings are automatically propagated to  your `cron` job. For example, there's no `$DISPLAY`, so GUI programs need special treatment (read `man xhost`). 
  
One can set environment variables for all one's `cron` jobs in the `crontab` file
 Read `man 5 crontab`.
  
Look at the results of  `echo "=== set ===";set;echo "=== env ===";env | sort;echo "=== alias ===";alias` in each of your environments.
  
Since the `comm

Comment: ...
Since the `command` part of the `crontab` line is, by default,  interpreted by `/bin/sh`, which has a simpler syntax than `/bin/bash`, I recommend having `command` be a call to a `bash` script  (executable, mounted, starts with `#!/bin/bash`) which sets up the environment,  then calls the desired program.a

Comment: Capturing the output was what I needed. Like this I found out that the problem was me. I had a line that used the username. But when you run the file with a cronjob the user is 'root'. That should be logical but took me about four hours of shouting at my computer and anxiously wheeping in front of the screen. Thx guys =).